# Convexity adjustment for futures/FRA under T+D measure

Tags: futures, pricing, convexity, rates

In an internal document in my company, the convexity adjustment for Futures is defined as:

[image: ConvAdj = E^Q(L(T,T,T+D)) - E^{Q^{T+D}}(L(T,T,T+D)) = E^{Q^{T+D}}(L(T,T,T+D)*(B_{T+D}*P(0,T+D)-1))]

where [image: B_{t} = exp(\int_{0}^{t}r_s*ds)] and P(0,T+D) is the ZC bond maturity at T+D.

I don't understand why [image: B_{T+D}*P(0,T+D)] is not equal to 1 as I thought they were the same except B has a positive sign in the integral while P has a negative sign.

Comment: I think it’s because $B_{T+D}$ is a random variable whereas $P(0,T+D)$ is known at time 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can't hold unless interest $B_{T+D}$ is deterministic.
Here's why:

You're imlpying that $$E^Q[L(T,T,T+D)] = B_{T+D}*P(0,T+D)*E^{Q^{T+D}}[L(T,T,T+D)]$$
Because all the terms in the equation are deterministic except $B_{T+D}$, this term itself must be deterministic.

In the case $B_{T+D}$ is deterministic we have the following relationship
$$P(0,T+D) = E^Q[\frac{1}{B_{T+D}}] = \frac{1}{B_{T+D}}$$

In this case your intuition is correct indeed.